# Cannot print from customize paper

Tags: windows, google-chrome, printing, printer

We need to do printing on a customize paper **5.5in H x 8.5in W**, from Google Chrome. We set the paper size in Windows Print Server.

But when we preview the printing from Google Chrome, the preview will auto change the paper size to **8.5in H x 5.5in W**.

I've try reverse the W and H setting of the customize paper in print server, make it **8.5in H and 5.5in W**, but the result still same. Google chrome looks like will auto take the shorter edge as width, and longer edge as height.

I can not change the paper orientation to landscape, because this will make the printer assume it's landscape and made the actual printout 90 degree rotated.

The paper is computer form with holes on both side, thus I can't rotate the paper in printer too.

Please advice how can I fix this.

The printer model is Epson LQ-310.

Comment: The paper sizes and handling of custom paper sizes are handled by the printer driver that will (in the end) do the actual work.  I am not an expert about Windows Print Server but I am indeed an expert about printer drivers as I have written over 100 of them.  Perhaps this will get you closer to answering your problem.  I myself would suggest getting the print server out of the way and seeing of you can do this with a direct connection and local driver.  Also,, writing code for custom paper sizes was a serious PITA so it wouldn't be surprising if there are bugs in there.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, I think you misunderstand, the **print server** is neither a hardware nor a computer. **print server** is a setting in Windows, I set custom paper size there.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: @Wicket, I test on Windows 10.

Comment: @ruby.lee , I think it is you that misunderstand (no offense).  The print server needs to convert a print job into a device context which in turn will be turned into a printer language specific print job.  This is device driver specific and implementation of paper size is done by the driver (TRUST ME).  Implementing custom paper sizes is a PITA and many people get it wrong.  It is *possible* that the server is interpreting something odd and trying to change the orientation of the page but is probably the driver.  Like I said.. not an expert at the server.

Comment: And even if I am wrong (as I often am), I wish you the best.